# OpenGL 4 headers

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-4

Where i can download OpenGL 4.0 headers for C/C++?
I found only `GL/gl.h` in `/compiler/include/`, but it outdated (OpenGL 1.1).

Don't offer libraries like GLEW. I want write my application with pure OpenGL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL core profile headers are located here:

http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glcorearb.h

This header contains only core profile and ARB extension interfaces, as described in appendix G.2 of the OpenGL 4.3 Specification. It does not include interfaces found only in the compatibility profile.

I think this is what you ask for when you say `OpenGL 4`.

Here are some OpenGL 4 tutorials:

- http://www.swiftless.com/opengl4tuts.html
- http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://rastertek.com/tutgl40.html He doesn't use any wrapper in his OGL 4.0 tutorials and managing APIENTRY's by himself.